# if output is empty do something else?

Tags: php

This code outputs info from a road. but sometimes there is no info, then I want to gather info from another place. How can I do this?

```
$title = '1234';

foreach(Feed('$url') as $f ) {
  if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false){
    $pos = $f->children('georss', true)->children('gml', true)->children('gml', true);
    list($number1, $number2) = explode(' ', $pos);
      if ($number1 > 0 && $number1 < 100){
        if ($number2 > 1 && $number2 < 10){
         echo $f->description. "<br>";
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

how can I make it so if this^^ has no results then do this:

```
    foreach(Feed('$url') as $f ) {
      if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false){
             echo $f->description. "<br>";
              }
            }
```

I know I can check if a variable is empty with using Len($variable) = 0. but i dont have an variable. how could i get this? then i guess i could do:

```
if (Len($variable) = 0) {
  foreach(Feed('$url') as $g ) {
    if (strpos($g->title, $title) !== false){
           echo $g->description. "<br>";
            }
          }
        }
```

I guess it is possible to have `foreach` inside `if`?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Smart! I didn't think of that. I really think your solution nr.1 will work well for the intention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a boolean variable to indicate if you found the description the first way, and if not, then find it the second way:

```php
$descriptionFound = false;

foreach(Feed('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=601') as $f) {
  if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false){
    $pos = $f->children('georss', true)->children('gml', true)->children('gml', true);
    list($number1, $number2) = explode(' ', $pos);

    if (
      $number1 > 59.417104 && $number1 < 60.089568
      && $number2 > 5.115812 && $number2 < 7.811784
    ) {
      $descriptionFound = true;
      echo $f->description . "<br>";
    }
  }
}

if (!$descriptionFound) {
  foreach(Feed('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=604') as $f) {
    if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false){
      echo $f->description . "<br>";
    }
  }
}
```

Similarly, you could store the description as you're checking various methods, and then output the value at the end:

```php
$description = '';

foreach(Feed('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=601') as $f) {
  if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false){
    $pos = $f->children('georss', true)->children('gml', true)->children('gml', true);
    list($number1, $number2) = explode(' ', $pos);

    if (
      $number1 > 59.417104 && $number1 < 60.089568
      && $number2 > 5.115812 && $number2 < 7.811784
    ) {
      $description .= $f->description . "<br>";
    }
  }
}

if (!$description) { //this will be falsy if it's an empty string, so no need to do == ''
  foreach(Feed('https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikk/xml/savedsearch.rss?id=604') as $f) {
    if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false){
      $description .= $f->description . "<br>";
    }
  }
}

echo $description;
```

Either would give you the same code flow and end result.